# Visual Studio 2017 community edition immediate window error: The expression cannot be evaluated while in run mode

Tags: c#

I want to execute different simple expressions in immediate windows fx. 1+1 but I get that error:

> "The expression cannot be evaluated while in run mode. "

1. I tried to make my project the current startup project but no success.
2. Tried to add ">" in front of 1+1 but no success.

I use VS 2017 Community edition.

I have used that immediate window without problem in vs 2015 so this is very annoying.

Comment: Use Debug > Break All

Comment: I don't see such an option under Debug in my VS